# Setting background color when user clicks, changing back when user clicks anywhere else

Tags: javascript, meteor, materialize

I have come across a situation where I want to set the background color of a list item `<li>` tag when the user clicks on that item.  I want it to remain that background color forever until the user clicks elsewhere on the page **except** another `<li>` tag.

In Meteor, I know how to use a `mousedown` or `click` event on the `<li>` tag to set the background color of itself, but how can set a Meteor `click` event on everything else that can reset the background color of that `<li>`?

I am using Meteor, Javascript, and Materialize CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `click` event listener on the `body` and check that target is different from your `li`

Comment: Sounds like that would work. In Meteor, where can I set a click event on the `<body>` tag?

Comment: Oh, I see a `Template.body.events()` in some documentation.  I will try it.  Thanks!